# Binding ObservableCollection<string[]> к DataGrid

Tags: wpf

Есть коллекция такого типа, и когда я привязываюсь к ней, то в первую колонку выводится не первый массив из коллекции, а элементы с индексом 0 всех вложенных массивов, и во вторую колонку элементы с индексом 1.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding NamesList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding [0]}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding [1]}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Как исправить это? Как вывести по массивам, а не по элементам?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133121/276994

Comment: @VladD, но это просто поворот таблицы. Выводить он всё равно будет также, тут дело не совсем в этом. Он биндинг по-другому выполняет...